# Expect the result of 2 promises to equal one thing (combine 2 promise arrays)

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have two promises, which are both returning arrays

```
let promise1 = Promise.resolve(['one', 'two']);
let promise2 = Promise.resolve(['three', 'four']);
```

I then want to expect that these two promises together equal one array like so:

```
expect(promise1.concat(promise2)).toEqual(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']);
```

The code above is simplified, and I know I could do 2 expect statements, but values can change between being in promise 1 or promise 2.

I've been messing around with then blocks to no avail...
How can I achieve the expect statement above? It doesn't have to be concat, I just want to combine these 2 promise arrays into 1.

Comment: not even `['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']` equals `['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']` because javsacript doesn't work that way

Comment: but, `promise1` wont equal `['one', 'two']` either, because promises don't work that way

Comment: The code is simplified, I'm not using Promise.resolve. I just thought it was an easy way to describe a promise that returns an array. Happy to edit it to something else if you have a suggestion

Comment: the toEqual method will return true for two arrays with the same values

Comment: `The code is simplified, I'm not using Promise.resolve` - sure, but you're using promises, and expect the promise to be an array, but the variable that holds a Promise is a promise of a value not the value itself

Comment: Are you saying what I'm trying to achieve can't be done? I have no trouble expecting single promises of a value to equal the value

Comment: guess I don't know how jasmine works then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to combine your promises and then accumulate their result into a single array using `reduce()`:

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve([1,2])
const promise2 = Promise.resolve([3,4])

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(result => {
  const combined = result.reduce((acc, result) => { 
     return acc.concat(result)
  }, [])
  
  console.log(combined)
})
```

This allows you to combine an arbitrary number of Arrays.

Comment: how will that help jasmine `expect ... equalTo`

Comment: It won't; The OP can just return `Promise.all()` in the test and do the equality check in `then`.

Comment: @DeejC Are you sure? Can you try and fail your test? Perhaps expect a different result to test if it fails. I suspect your test will always be green.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides You're right. I could have sworn I made the test fail first, but now it is always passing

Comment: Are you doing something similar to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/o9v464dc/)?

Comment: Okay I was wrong, I was actually implementing Dominic's answer as it was less lines and I thought both answers were returning the same result. Using the reduce method you outlined, when I expect the wrong result the test fails

Comment: It doesn't make sense for my answer to work while Dominic's doesn't. Both are conceptually identical.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're after because you've basically already written it!

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(['one', 'two']);
const promise2 = Promise.resolve(['three', 'four']);

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(([result1, result2]) =>
   console.log(result1.concat(result2))
);
```

If you need to de-dupe the array there are a number of ways not sure if that's what you need though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on ["how does expect work"](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/128) on GitHub, try:

```
expect(
    Promise.all( promise1, promise2)
    .then(
         results=>results.reduce( (acc, result) => acc.concat( result), [])
    )
).toEqual(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']);
```

`Promise.all` fulfills with an array of individual promise results. The `then` clause concatenates each result array into a combined accumulator array (using `reduce` as in @NicholasKyriakides answer). `expect` should then process the final promise, returned by `.then`, as described in the link:

> ```
> expect(promise).toEqual('foo');
> ```
>
> ... will essentially be replaced with:
>
> ```
> promise.then(function(value) {
>      expect(value).toEqual('foo');
> }
> ```